# using a chart with values from textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, controls

I'm trying to make a pie chart that uses values from a user from text box's.  I'm using c# windows forms chart control.

The problem is where to assign the text box's as values.

- Is it done in code? if so what do I call?
- Is it done in the control properties? if so what do I do?
- Is it a bit of both? is so, well same as both above.

I've attempted to make one using the properties wizard but I cant see where to assign the values for it to process, the data source seem to only allow objects and connections to Dbos.
I'm hoping this is a really simple process I'm overlooking.

Yes I've checked MSDN but not a lot of info on the specifics I require.  Yes I've checked google but again there is either no info or info on building my own from scratch (which I have done, but looks really bad)

this is some code ive tried

```
         double[] yValues = { 10, 8, 7, 12};
        string[] xNames = { "Greater than 200", "Between 200-100", "Between 100-50", "Below 50" };

        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
        chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
        chart1.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
        chart1.Series[3].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
```

it errors at series[2], saying the index was out of range.  Im guessing it something to do with how the chart is currently set up

::UPDATED::
Ok so i was right i didnt assign enough series to the chart (silly me).  Ive managed to get it up and running.....unfortunatly the image display looks like.....a letter(wierd).
Its a box with a cross in the middle all equal aswell.  I would at least think its would display proportional to the values i sent.  so is this a set up OR is there something im doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something like this.
Where you would plug your y values directly from your textboxes.

```
   double[] yValues = { 10, 27.5, 7, 12, 45.5};
    string[] xNames = { “Mike”, “John”, “William”, “George”, “Alex” };
   myChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
```

Comment: ahhhh i see, so create chart using the gui, then manually set it using chart.series[array].points.databind(x,y). ill take a look at this also

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code with explanations:

http://forum.codecall.net/csharp-tutorials/7917-tutorial-vs2008-c-pie-chart.html#post43094

I think it's doing exactly what you want to do

Comment: hehe, thats the EXACT tutorial i followed and got working, the problem is....it looks soo bad, the graphics are really really bad.  hence why im looking into using the form control version since it looks better and can be made to 3d i believe.

Comment: You should've posted it in your question, so people would where you are.

Answer (score 0):

maybe an idea to take a look at zedgraph:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

this chart class can make pie-charts among other things

Comment: ill take a look, "noob question of the day" never used other class libs before, in visual studio where do i put the downloaded source files?

Comment: maybe the easiest way is DL the example at the top of the page and rebuild it towards your own project
(my rule nr 1 of programming: When not knowing what to do, find an example that does what you need, run it step by step to see what it does, rebuild it by yourself)